# VBA - Use Date Variable in SQL Query instead of GETDATE()

Tags: excel, vba

I have a query that works fine using GETDATE() as the date reference, which collects the data for those in the age range.
However, I would like to use a floating DATE reference point, so that age is calculated from a provided (dd/mm/yyyy) date rather than the current datetime

How do I change GETDATE() in the query after the WHERE clause below to work with a variable date as in aYear to get my age range?

NOTE: The data is being extracted from a PostGres data-set into Excel 2010 using an SQL query

```
Dim sAge As Integer
    sAge = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT").Range("B5")    'AGE FROM
Dim eAge As Integer
    eAge = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT").Range("C5")    'AGE TO
Dim aDate As String
    aDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT").Range("D5")   'CALC AGE USING THIS DATE
    aYear = Format(aDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")

Dim abc As String
abc = "SELECT c.id, p.dob, [AGE NOW] = dbo.AGE(p.dob, GETDATE()) " _
    & "FROM table c INNER JOIN person p ON c.id=p.id " _
    & "WHERE ( dbo.AGE(p.dob, GETDATE()) >= " & [sAge] & " AND dbo.AGE(p.dob, GETDATE()) <= " & [eAge] & " ) " _

Set rs = conn.Execute(abc)
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Refresh
End With

rs.Close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `dbo.AGE(p.dob, GETDATE())` to `dbo.AGE(p.dob, '" & aYear & "')`

Note that when you concatenate the string you aren't including quotes, so you have to wrap the single quotes around the double quotes so that they exist in the string.

Something to consider is that you'll be passing the date as a string, so if the date you concatenate in isn't in a format that Postgres "doesn't like" you could see issues.  Just something to keep in mind as you test the output.

Comment: I used " & aYear & ". It was the single quotes I was missing Thank you works a treat now.